# How to include list comprehension result in django-filter?

Tags: python, django, list-comprehension, django-filter

I am using django-filter to display my results in django

However I have to filter some results based on the properties in the model I have to also use list comprehension

```
def extra_available_list(request):
    EXTEND = "rent_base.html"
    extra_list_gen = ExtraFilter(request.GET, queryset=Extra.objects.all().order_by('is_parking'))
    extra_list = [obj for obj in extra_list_gen if ((obj.lease)==0)]

    paginator = Paginator(extra_list, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        extra_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        extra_page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        extra_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,'unit/extra_list.html', {'extra': extra_list,'page_extra':extra_page})
```

How can incorporate my output from list comprehension into my django filter?

---

UPDATE

I tried suggested solution

```
extra_list_gen = Extra.objects.all()
extra_list_ids = [obj for obj in extra_list_gen if ((obj.lease)==0)]
extra_list = ExtraFilter(request.GET, queryset=Extra.objects.filter(id__in=extra_list_ids).order_by('is_parking'))
```

but I get an error

> int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Extra'
>
> ```
>             extra_list = ExtraFilter(request.GET, queryset=Extra.objects.filter(id__in=extra_list_ids).order_by('is_parking'))
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need a queryset you could do something like this

```
# First get the ids that you want, saving the id to the list
extra_objects_ids = [obj.id for obj in Extra.objects.all() if ((obj.lease)==0)]

# Now filter using id__in and then order
extra_queryset = Extra.objects.filter(id__in=extra_objects_ids).order_by('is_parking')
```

Comment: You missed the ".id" on the list comprehension. You need to get a list of ids, not a list of objects.

Comment: I'm assuming this should be used with a certain amount of caution to prevent a model with many many entries from using up additional resources.